# Is there an option to increase the number of turns in a game?

Tags: delve-deeper

25 turns doesn't seem quite long enough. Is there any way to make the game last longer?

Edit: Just noticed that turn count varies based on the map, but the question still stands.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, just found it. That's simple enough. On the map selection screen, clicking on "Game Length" will allow you to change the number of turns.